# Ratio Test for Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that if $a_n$ is bounded and $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$, then $a_n$ converges?

I know that ratio test tells us nothing when the limit of the ratio is 1. However, I am wondering, what if we have an extra condition that the sequence is also bounded. Is it true then that the sequence is convergent when the limit of the ratio is 1? Can someone provide me with a counterexample, or proof that it is true? Thanks.

Comment: If the sequence is unbounded, then the series is automatically divergent. So the boundedness condition does not do anything for you. For instance, the harmonic series $\sum 1/n$ is a counterexample.

Comment: What you call the ratio test is taken, by many, as the well-known test for infinite positive series. What do you mean here? I can't see the tag of series...

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan harmonic series 1/n is not bounded so, it is not a counterexample.

Comment: @user2675516, I think you're mixing stuff here: what you probably meant is that the sequence *of partial sums of the harmonic series* is not bounded...

Comment: @DonAntonio Anyway, I am not dealing with series here, I am dealing with sequence. So it is not about the partial sum, is just that the term of the sequence is not bounded

Comment: But you're the one who mentioned the harmonic series just two comments above, @user2675516 ...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Let $b_n$ be a bounded sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_{n+1}-b_n)=0$ and $b_n$ does not converge, like
$$
1,\frac12,0,\frac13,\frac23,1,\frac34,\frac24,\frac14,0,\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45,1,\frac56,\dots,
$$
and let $a_n=e^{b_n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the harmonic series start adding the numbers $1/n$ until you hit an upper bound that you like, say 100 or 17 or whatever.  Now instead of adding the next terms start subtracting them, keep doing this until you hit a positive lower bound you like.  Once you hit this lower bound start adding terms until you hit the upper bound again, rinse and repeat ad nauseam.

The partial sums of this signed harmonic series will bounce between your upper and lower bounds, but the ratios of successive terms will tend to 1 (for this you need your lower bound to be positive).

Comment: i don't think this example is right, it does not fulfil the question condition. a_n is both bounded and ration is equal to 1, so u either have the entire series be defined as a_n, then the ratio is not 1, or u have the term 1/n be defined as a_n which converges. Here u r saying the summation of a_n is bounded and the ratio of the term of the summation is 1.

Comment: I'm having the partial sums be $a_n$. Since I am bounding my sequence away from zero for $n$ large enough $\frac{a_n}{a_n \pm \frac{1}{n}} = \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ tends to 1.